# Fluent-bit - Parse kubernetes JSON log message into structured fields

Tags: json, parsing, kubernetes, fluent-bit

I have a basic fluent-bit configuration that outputs Kubernetes logs to New Relic. The log message format is just horrible and I couldn't really find a proper way to parse them, they look like this:

```
"\"{\"correlation_id\":\"058537f6906593eb8b5de90e515e6f79\",\"datetime\":\"2021-01-12T09:16:57Z\",\"level\":\"info\",\"message\":\"request\",\"payload\":{\"request\":{\"host\":\"hidden.co.uk\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"path\":\"/api/v1/access/acs\",\"proto\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"realIP\":\"10.99.26.212\",\"referer\":\"http://m.facebook.com\",\"remoteAddr\":\"0.0.0.0:58576\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBDV/iPhone12,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/14.3;FBSS/2;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_GB;FBOP/5]\"},\"response\":{\"latency\":6,\"size\":0,\"status\":307}},\"request\":{\"host\":\"hidden.co.uk\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"path\":\"/api/v1/access/acs\",\"proto\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"realIP\":\"10.99.26.212\",\"referer\":\"http://m.facebook.com\",\"remoteAddr\":\"0.0.0.0:58576\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBDV/iPhone12,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/14.3;FBSS/2;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_GB;FBOP/5]\"},\"request_id\":\"81efd22f-5022-44d8-9415-c6ff6b98bb54\",\"response\":{\"latency\":6,\"size\":0,\"status\":307},\"timestamp\":1610443017}\"\n"
```

Config is as follows:

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     ${LOG_LEVEL}
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-newrelic.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              ${PATH}
        Parser            ${LOG_PARSER}
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     7MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name record_modifier
        Match kube.*
        Record cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME}

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
        Merge_Log           Off
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
        Labels              On
        Annotations         On

  output-newrelic.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name  newrelic
        Match *
        licenseKey ${NRIA_LICENSE_KEY}
        endpoint ${ENDPOINT}

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name         docker
        Format       json
        Time_Key     time
        Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep    On
        Decode_Field_As   escaped    log

    [PARSER]
        Name cri
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
```

I'm new to Fluent-bit and the documentation seems rather confusing, so I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Merge_Log` to `On`.

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/kubernetes

> When enabled, it checks if the log field content is a JSON string map, if so, it append the map fields as part of the log structure.